# How to safely update all gems in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Rails applications can have hundreds of dependencies which, left unchecked, typically all need to be updated periodically. After running `bundle outdated` and getting a list of 100+ gems that are out of date, I'm a bit daunted at the prospect of looking up every single one, finding its CHANGELOG, and confirming that the update doesn't break anything. There doesn't even seem to be a confirmed way to [update a single gem](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/3025) without pulling in all of its dependencies.

I found [this project](https://github.com/lpender/bummr) which is supposed to update each gem in a separate commit after passing automated tests. That would help streamline the process but it doesn't tell you which gem version upgrades include DSL changes (such as [this one](https://github.com/aasm/aasm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400)). Sometimes I blindly update minor or patch versions without checking, hoping the author follows a [SEMVER](http://semver.org/)-like versioning convention. Other times there is no documentation (no History or CHANGELOG files).

When I write my own code I'm sure to review every line before committing it. Should the same vigilance apply to updating libraries? Usually there wasn't much diligence performed when including the library in the first place. But in a greenfield project there is little to lose and much to be gained by leveraging other people's code. In a mature project there is little tolerance for new failures.

Are there any tools or processes for pulling in updates one a time, viewing the changes in a diff-like way, viewing the CHANGELOG if any, and running the test suite?

Answer (score 3):

My strategy is to only update a few gems at time whenever it's possible to do so. Obviously dependency trees can make this difficult but I've been burned a few times with blindly running `bundle update`, particularly in large projects with 100+ gems and this avoid it if possible. Updating smaller groups of gems also provides an additional benefit in that any side-effects are easier to isolate and address.

Also, I try to make a habit of using dedicated git commits for any changes to Gemfile/Gemfile.lock. So any and all dependency updates have a single commit containing  changes for those two files only. This makes debugging much easier with `git bisect` and changes are easy to revert if the need arises. It also helps the inevitable trial-and-error process of dependency resolution. I've found this strategy works well for migrations as well (though migrations are trickier than dependencies IMO).

Of course, every once in a while an update for a major dependency like Rails, Sidekiq, ActiveAdmin, RSpec, et. al. comes along, but that's relatively infrequent and having maintained the "thinner" dependencies makes this pill a bit easier to swallow.